# Sharing contacts on HTC Desire HD

Tags: contacts, share-menu

I have a stock Desire HD using HTC Sense and am having trouble sharing contacts. When I choose mail as a method to send contacts it doesn't offer me the choice to use my Gmail account?

Anyone have any idea why?

Really wish there was an option to turn off sense without rooting :(

Comment: What options does it offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 suggestions which are more workarounds than answers:

- set up the Mail app to access (and send from) your GMail account via IMAP, or
- send the contact to your GMail account using the 'Mail' option (i.e. from whatever account you do have set up) and then forward it on from there.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, having tried a few things, I installed a free app called qr code (barcode for the app: http://db.tt/sNcfBdS) and used that to create and send a mail with it attached.

Again, a work around rather than a direct solution but thought I would share what I did. This has the limitation that you can't share contacts which you have lots of data stored for unless you only choose to share a couple if bits of info (which qr code lets you do).

The answer seems to be that you can't use your gmail unless you do so via imap, so i have marked matt h's as an answer.